# Docking Top/Bottom/Left/Right/Filling in WPF

Tags: wpf

i am win form developer. whenever i want to set any control at top/Bottom/Left/Right position in its container then we just play the controls dock property in winform. so just guide me how can i place a control in its container top/Bottom/Left/Right position in such a way as a result when contain size change then control position will not change in wpf.

after searching google i came to know how filling works with Dock property and it is like

```
<Window ...Other window props... >
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <!-- Canvas items here... -->
    </Canvas>
</Window>
```

So guide me how to set any control at top/Bottom/Left/Right position in its container  with code snippet.

### UPDATE

i just come to know dock panel can be use for my requirement like this way

```
<DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <Button Content="Dock=Top" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Bottom" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Left"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Right" DockPanel.Dock="Right"/>
    <Button Content="LastChildFill=True"/>
</DockPanel>
```

any other way can i achieve this without using DockPanel. thanks

Comment: You could use the [DockPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.aspx) control.

Comment: Why don't you want to use DockPanel? It's what it's there for :P...

Comment: DockPanel is indeed the right component to do it. You could also use a simple Grid, but DockPanel is appropriate if you have a central element that define the position of the other elements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use a Grid, (note the star sizing)

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!-- If not specified, then Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" are defaults-->
    <Button Content="Dock=Top" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Bottom" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Left" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Right" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" />
    <Button Content="LastChildFill=True" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

You can use margins and alignments (margins are approximate here)

```
<Grid>
    <Button Content="Dock=Top" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Bottom" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,35"/>
    <Button Content="Dock=Right" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,35" />
    <Button Content="LastChildFill=True" Margin="75,35"/>
</Grid>
```

You can use StackPanels (this one needs more work to make it fill the space)

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">        
    <Button Content="Dock=Top" />
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
    <Button Content="Dock=Left" />
        <Button Content="LastChildFill=True" />
        <Button Content="Dock=Right" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Dock=Bottom" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: thanks for answer.we use anchor property in winform....is there anything similar in wpf like anchor property?

Comment: Sounds like its similar to the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment, try this explanation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751709.aspx There are links to HA and VA in there too.

Comment: i like to ask u a question because i feel u r sound enough in WPF. is there any site which provide huge sample code for wpf only for developing glossy attractive UI. i search google but found none. if u r aware then please give me those url. thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
 <DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Left"></Button>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" Content="Right"></Button>

    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Top"></Button>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Content="Bottom"></Button>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Left" Content="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></Button>

</DockPanel>
```